# How do I enter the key and values in postman "form-data" if there is json data with a file

Tags: javascript, json, object, postman

How do I enter the key and values in postman "form-data" if there is json data with a file, the data is

```
{
  "qr_code": "asckdmcw",
  "qr_name": "nCJNDCIEW",
  "bank_details": {
    "ifsc": "cxIEQJHFQU",
    "account_number": "CNQEIFH2eq",
    "customer_name": "dacLJDHC"
  }
}
```

i tried doing this

```
"bank_details.ifsc"
"bank_details.account_number"
"bank_details.customer_name"
```

but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Select Body -> form-data -> Enter your parameter name (file according to your code)

On the right side of the Key field, while hovering your mouse over it, there is a dropdown menu to select between Text/File. Select File, then a "Select Files" button will appear in the Value field.

For rest of "text" based parameters, you can post it like normally you do with postman. Just enter parameter name and select "text" from that right side dropdown menu and enter any value for it, hit send button. Your controller method should get called.

Answer (score 0):

Select Body -> form-data -> Bulk edit
then paste this

```
qr_code: asckdmcw
qr_name: nCJNDCIEW
bank_details["ifsc"]: cxIEQJHFQU
bank_details["account_number"]: CNQEIFH2eq
bank_details["customer_name"]: dacLJDHC
```